# Warning: [react-router] Location "/add" did not match any routes

Tags: react-router

I am stuck with react-router routing. I am getting the error:
Warning: [react-router] Location "/add" did not match any routes`
// conf.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link} from "react-router-dom";
import add  from './add';
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';
import confv1 from './confv1';
var button =React.createElement(Link, {
  to: "/add"
}, React.createElement("button", {
  type: "button"
}, "Add a project"));

  export default class Root extends Component {
    render() {
      return (


React.createElement(Router, {
  history: createBrowserHistory()
}, React.createElement(Route, {
  path: "/conf",
  component: confv1
}, React.createElement(Route, {
  component: conf
}), React.createElement(Route, {
  path: "/add",
  component: add
})
)));
      // );this is the conf page
```

[and this is the add page when I refresh it I got the error "Warning: [react-router] Location "/add" did not match any routes`"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Qh73.png)
        }
      }

`

Comment: Hi, Can you please share your code?

Comment: could u help me, please!!

Comment: @oumaimatirar which version of react-router-dom do you use? And pay attention that your Route element with 'add' path is a child of Route element with 'conf' path

Comment: "react-router-dom": "^5.0.0",

Comment: I don't know how to resolve the problem any help, please?  I don't know why when I refresh the Add page, I got this error. what is the problem exactly

Comment: i resolve the error with

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the error with a routes.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, IndexRoute } from 'react-router';
import App from './App';
import conf from './conf';
import add from './add';


export default (
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
        <IndexRoute component={conf} />
        <Route path="/conf" component={conf} >
        <IndexRoute component={add} />
        <Route path="/add" component={add} />
           </Route>

    </Route>

);
```

//index.js

```
import 'babel-polyfill';
import React from 'react';

import {render} from 'react-dom';
import {Router, BrowserRouter } from 'react-router';
import routes from './routes';
import {browserHistory} from 'react-router';

const history = require("history").createBrowserHistory();


render(
    <Router history={browserHistory} routes={routes} />, document.getElementById('root')
)
```

but when I refresh the add page nothing shows in the content[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iVXHL.png)

Answer (score 0):

I noticed from your code snippet that you are using two different npm packages, and I am wondering if that is part of the issue.

under Config.js you called:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link} from "react-router-dom";
```

Then under index.js you called:

```
import {Router, BrowserRouter } from 'react-router';
```

if that doesn't fix the issue could you create a codesandbox so I can take a look?
https://codesandbox.io/

Here is more information about the two npm packages you were trying to use:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-dom
good luck!